# creating a rectangle from 2 specific points

Tags: java, awt, java-2d, shapes

**I am trying to create a rectangle in Java** but only with **awt package** classes.

I can only **click two points and the program must calculate the width and height** and draw a rectangle between those exact two points.

The following doesn't work for me:

```
package ie.iact.shapes;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;

public class Rect extends Shapes {``

    private Point secondPoint;

    public Rect(Point f, Point s) {
        setFirstPoint(f);
        setSecondPoint(s);

    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        int x1 = firstPoint.x;
        int y1 = firstPoint.y;
        int x2 = secondPoint.x;
        int y2 = secondPoint.y;
        int a;
        int b;
        if (x1 < x2) {
            a = x1;
        } else {
            a = x2;
        }
        if (y1 < y2) {
            b = y1;
        } else {
            b = y2;
        }
        int width = secondPoint.x - a;
        int hight = secondPoint.y - b;
        g.drawRect(getFirstPoint().x, getFirstPoint().y, secondPoint.x, secondPoint.y);

    }

    public Point getSecondPoint() {
        return secondPoint;
    }

    public void setSecondPoint(Point secondPoint) {
        this.secondPoint = secondPoint;
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the g.drawRect call. You go to all the trouble of calculating the top/left corner and the height and width, but ten ignore tis values completely...

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: thank u all but the code was perfect. I was overriding it in another class

Answer (score 9):

**[Rectangle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#add%28java.awt.Point%29)** class can already handle all of your calculations:

```
Rectangle rect= new Rectangle(point1);
rect.add(point2);

g.fillRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use [`setFrameFromDiagonal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/RectangularShape.html#setFrameFromDiagonal(java.awt.geom.Point2D,%20java.awt.geom.Point2D)):

```
Rectangle rect= new Rectangle();
rect.setFrameFromDiagonal(point1, point2);

g.fillRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
```